# how to copy result of the linux command into a string using c code?

Tags: c, linux, command

I have executed a command "watch grep \"cpu MHz \" /proc/cpuinfo".After executing this command i got following result.
[Result of The Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bk9q.png)

But when I am trying this command using c code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    char path[1035];
    char command[]="watch grep \"cpu MHz \" /proc/cpuinfo";
    fp = popen(command, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("Failed to run command\n" );
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */
    while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {
        printf("%s",path);
    }
    pclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
    I am getting following result.
```

[Result of The Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDNww.jpg)
tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try enclosing the whole command you pass to `watch` in single quotes. E.g. `"watch 'grep \"cpu MHz\" /proc/cpuinfo'";`

Comment: Yes it is showing correct result but it is taking almost 1 min for showing the result.

Comment: That's because the output of the `watch` command contains no newline characters, so `fgets` is not returning until the `path` buffer is full. By the way, you don't need to use `sizeof(path)-1` in your call to `fgets`. You can just use `sizeof(path)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *fp;
    char path[1035];
    char command[]="while grep \"cpu MHz\" /proc/cpuinfo; do sleep 2; done";
    fp = popen(command, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("Failed to run command\n" );
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */
    while (fgets(path, sizeof(path), fp) != NULL) {
        printf("%s",path);
    }
    pclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes It is working.Can you please explain it a little?How is it giving correct result now without any delay?

Comment: @Yunis Khan - This is showing each line immediately because not the single command `watch …` is called which buffers all its output to the pipe until the buffer is full, but rather the command `grep …` is called repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.
Don't forget to use `memset`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char path[1035];
    char command[]="watch grep 'cpu MHz'  /proc/cpuinfo";

    fp = popen(command, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to run command\n" );
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(path,'\0',sizeof(path));
    /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */
    while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {
        printf("%s",path);
    }
    pclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is showing the same result which I have included at Result of The Code link but I need the result which I have included at Result of the command link.